# How to assign a master key to the pipeline to use HLS content protection with Elastic transcoder Amazon web service

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline

How to assign a master key to the pipeline to use HLS content protection with Elastic transcoder Amazon web service?

I am using following code to assign a master key to pipeline by providing value for "AwsKmsKeyArn key" into createPipeline function

```
$pipelineresult = $ElasticTranscoderClient->createPipeline(array(
'Name' => 'awsdemo',
'InputBucket' => 'my_input_bucket_name',
'OutputBucket' => 'my_outut_bucket_name',
'Role' => 'arn:aws:iam::************:role/Elastic_Transcoder_Default_Role',
'StorageClass' => 'Standard',
```

I'm observing following key value as a master key for pipeline

```
'AwsKmsKeyArn' => 'arn:aws:kms:us-west-2:425157612114:key/********-****-****-****-************'
));
```

But i'm not able to find master key after login into my AWS console and look into created pipeline. Please help me to set master key to pipeline so that i can implement HLS content protection.